# sshtunnel doesn't recognize private key password

Tags: python, private-key, ssh-tunnel, ssh-agent

I'm using sshtunnel to connect to connect to a remote server and on to a database from there. Everything is working fine, except that sshtunnel doesn't seem to recognize my `ssh_private_key_password` unless I've already entered it elsewhere (or more likely I'm making a mistake when providing it).

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('my.server', 22),
    ssh_username="myUsername",
    ssh_pkey="~/.ssh/id_rsa", 
    ssh_private_key_password="myPassword",
    remote_bind_address=("other.server", 3306)
) as server:
{do some stuff}
```

If I log into "my.server" separately and enter my private key password in the dialog for storage by ssh-agent, and *then* run the code above, it works as expected.

If I run the code *without* having already logged into the server at some point earlier, I receive this error: `ValueError: No password or public key available!` (But the password is there - ssh_private_key_password - no?)

This happens whether `ssh_pkey` is pointing to the public key *or* the private key.

What might be happening here? Am I misunderstanding something about the expected arguments for SSHTunnelForwarder? Something more fundamental about the key and password?

Comment: Hi, did you work out what the issue was? We're having the same problem!

Comment: Is the user that you run this script same with the user that owns the key?

Comment: Maybe the problem is the format of the private key. The private key file `id_rsa`  should be start like `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, not with the title of `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`.

Answer (score 9):

I have worked through this problem.

In my case, my macOS `~/.ssh/id_rsa` start with `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` which is not the proper start line.

In fact, the `ssh_pkey` should be started with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`. According to the source code of `sshtunnel` model:

```py
ssh_pkey (str or paramiko.PKey):
    **Private** key file name (``str``) to obtain the public key
    from or a **public** key (:class:`paramiko.pkey.PKey`)
```

The key is a `paramiko.pkey.PKey`, that means, the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` should be convert to paramiko.pkey correctly.

```py
import paramiko
pkey='~/.ssh/id_rsa'
key=paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(pkey)

# id_rsa with `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`
# raise SSHException: not a valid RSA private key file
```

So, I generate a new key in a linux OS, with command of `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, then 
I authorize access to the key with `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@jump_server_host -p ssh_port`.

```sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@jump_server_host -p ssh_port
```

now the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` on my linux OS looks like:

```sh
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAuFSEXjLMwyAJ54d5hQQjyIE+4l5pZw7GuYFDgNCzXjl6CNwV
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Copy it to my local mac, and test it.

```py
pkey='/path/to/the/new/id_rsa'
key=paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(pkey) 

# id_rsa with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
# No SSHException now.
```

Now, it works without Exception `ValueError: No password or public key available!`.

```py
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('jump_server_host', jump_ssh_port),  # jump server
        ssh_username='username',
        ssh_pkey="/path/to/new/id_rsa",
        remote_bind_address=('remote_host', remote_ssh_port),  # remote_server
        local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 30023)                  # local_bind_port set to 30023, your can select new one 
) as server:
    server.start()
    print(server.local_bind_port)
    server.close()
```

It outputs `30023`.

Comment: Thank you Ferris, changing the key format to PEM format (i.e. what gives you that opening line of `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`) is what solved this problem for me as well. If you don't have access to a Linux OS, you can actually change an existing OPENSSH key in-place to PEM with a one-liner: `ssh-keygen -p -N "new passphrase" -m pem -f /path/to/key`. This will leave your public key unchanged so you don't need to add or change anything on the remote machine. Via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994641/openssh-private-key-to-rsa-private-key.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you should add the **private key**

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue, by running below command on my machine. I am able to resolve this issue.

```
$ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage all users of the platform to be as informative as possible when answering a question. Please include a reason why your approach resolves the issue and when possible provide resource links for further understanding of the topic. These are just a couple of different approaches to making sure your answer is clear and understandable. Thank you for your participation!

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't found a solution, in my case, the problem was the path to the private key.
Instead of using:

`ssh_pkey="~/.ssh/id_rsa",`

Use (for example) the *absolute path*:

`ssh_pkey="/Users/<your-user>/.ssh/id_rsa",`

From my analysis, the problem was the check that the key exists in sshtunnel:
https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L1018

`os.path.exists(ssh_pkey)` is False when using `~/.ssh/id_rsa` path

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that this error can also show up if you provide an invalid password to the private key. I just tested now with paramiko==2.8.1 and I provided a gibberish password and got the same error message. The initial password was from a password manager and had many special characters so it's also worth to look into this as well.

Answer (score -2):

I met the same issue yesterday. The code I used worked well before. But after three months it can not work with "No password or public key available" exception. I found my paramiko version was 2.5, so I update it to 2.7. Then the code can work well again.