# gitlab CI : Error loading key : invalid format

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, gitlab-ci

I'm stuck with this problem since 2 days.

Tried with id_rsa.pub and id_rsa from my production server, still the same error...
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY is a variable I created in the CI/CD Settings on GitLab.

edit : not protected, not masked.

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# Official framework image. Look for the different tagged releases at:
# https://hub.docker.com/r/library/node/tags/
image: node:alpine

stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    # Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
    # (change apt-get to yum if you use a CentOS-based image)
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apk add --update openssh )'

    # Add bash
    - apk add --update bash

    # Add git
    - apk add --update git

    # Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

    # Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -

    # For Docker builds disable host key checking. Be aware that by adding that
    # you are suspectible to man-in-the-middle attacks.
    # WARNING: Use this only with the Docker executor, if you use it with shell
    # you will overwrite your user's SSH config.
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    # In order to properly check the server's host key, assuming you created the
    # SSH_SERVER_HOSTKEYS variable previously, uncomment the following two lines
    # instead.
    # - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    # - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo "$SSH_SERVER_HOSTKEYS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
  script:
  - npm i -g pm2
  - pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js production
  only:
  - master
```

And when I run the pipeline, I still get this error...

```
$ echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
Error loading key "(stdin)": invalid format
```

Could you please help ? I'm helpless, clueless, hopeless loading...

Thanks very much !

Comment: Did you copy the entire contents of the private key?https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor

Comment: I did copy the whole result of the "cat .ssh/id_rsa" into the variable, GitLab UI. The private key has been generated with the command "ssh-keygen -t rsa" run on the server where I want the files to be sended !

Comment: @jww This is 100% relevant for Stack Overflow, and I have answered numerous similar questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> SSH_PRIVATE_KEY is a variable I created in the CI/CD Settings on GitLab.

This is [documented here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor)

> in the Value field paste the content of your private key that you created earlier.

So make sure you have pasted the `id_rsa` full content, including `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` (with 5 final `-`)
(And, as [MrDuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143724/mrduk) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143027/gitlab-ci-error-loading-key-invalid-format/58143535#comment121310290_58143535), a final newline)

[Stephane Paquet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839787/stephane-paquet) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143027/gitlab-ci-error-loading-key-invalid-format/58143535?noredirect=1#comment110454445_58143535):

> ```
> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa | pbcopy
> ```
>
> to make sure you copy all the required information.

Comment: DAMN ! I didn't get the "BEGIN" was *before* this line... Thanks very much !

Comment: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa | pbcopy` to make sure you copy all the required information

Comment: @StephanePaquet Thank you for this feedback. Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: For future googlers, also make sure you have a newline at the end of your file.

Comment: @MrDuk Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Tried everything but nothing worked. In docs they say that ed25519 is generated wrong, fixed still same issue. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor

Comment: @iamandrewluca OK, I see you have found a solution. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to change CI/CD Variable type from `Variable` to `File`.
And instead of sourcing from the variable, did the sourcing from the file where `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` is pointing

```bash
chmod 600 $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
ssh-add $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an FYI for anyone else doing this, I had the same problem but had missed the final dash off the END RSA PRIVATE KEY section. It must have 5 dashes as the dividers, apparently.

Comment: Just run in the same issue and messed around it for a while. It not only requires the dashes, but also another newline after them.

Answer (score 1):

Also just as an FYI, my issue was that my SSH key was an OpenSSH format key (ex. `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`) instead of a PEM format key (`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`), if you want instructions on how to convert an OpenSSH key to a PEM key you can find the answer here: [Openssh Private Key to RSA Private Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994641/openssh-private-key-to-rsa-private-key)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is the way how the gitlab handles the "\n" in the string.  So, instead o creating a variable with content of the private key ( a bunch of "\n" ), convert it to base64 (no "\n" characters):

```
base64 -w 0 .ssh/id_rsa
```

Then copy the output (don't forget the "=") to your variable SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

In the stage (gitlab-ci.yml):

```
- echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY | base64 -d > rsa.key
- ssh -i rsa user@host "echo hello world;"
```