# How to run a cron job as a non-root user and log the job's output?

Tags: linux, docker, cron, alpine-linux

[Docker best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) state:

> If a service can run without privileges, use USER to change to a non-root user.

In the case of `cron`, that doesn't seem practical as `cron` needs root privileges to function properly. The executable that `cron` runs, however, does NOT need root privileges. Therefore, I run `cron` itself as the `root` user, but call my `crontab` script to run the executable (in this case, a simple Python FTP download script I wrote) as a non-root user via the `crontab -u <user>` command.

The cron/Docker interactability and community experience still seems to be in its infancy, but there are some pretty good solutions out there. Utilizing lessons gleaned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934762/why-is-crond-failing-to-run-a-non-root-crontab-on-alpine-linux) great posts, I arrived at a Dockerfile that looks something like this:

```
FROM python:3.7.4-alpine

RUN adduser -S riptusk331
WORKDIR /home/riptusk331

... boilerplate not necessary to post here ...

COPY mycron /etc/cron.d/mycron
RUN chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/mycron
RUN crontab -u riptusk331 /etc/cron.d/mycron

CMD ["crond", "-f", "-l", "0"]
```

and the `mycron` file is just a simple python execution running every minute

```
* * * * * /home/riptusk331/venv/bin/python3 /home/riptusk331/ftp.py
```

This works perfectly fine, but I am unsure of how exactly logging is being handled here. I do not see anything saved in `/var/log/cron`. I can see the output of `cron` and `ftp.py` on my terminal, as well as in the container logs if I pull it up in Kitematic. But I have no idea what is actually going on here.

So my first question(s) are: ***how is logging & output being handled here (without any redirects after the cron job), and is this implementation method ok & secure?***

VonC's answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container) suggests appending `> /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2` to your cron job to redirect output to Docker's `stdout` and `stderr`. This is where I both get a little confused, and run into trouble.

My crontab file now looks like this

```
* * * * * /home/riptusk331/venv/bin/python3 /home/riptusk331/ftp.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

1. The output without any redirection ***appeared*** to be going to stdout/stderr already, but I am not entirely sure. I just know it was showing up on my terminal. So why would this redirect be needed?
2. When I add this redirect, I run into permissioning issues. Recall that this crontab is being called as the *non-root user* `riptusk331`. Because of this, I don't have root access and get the following error:

```
/bin/ash: can't create /proc/1/fd/1: Permission denied
```

Comment: @jww Again? ([after yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143027/gitlab-ci-error-loading-key-invalid-format/58143535#comment102700591_58143027)). This is 100% on-topic for Stack Overflow, and I have answered such questions before. For *years*.

Comment: @jww But, as always, thank you for your moderation efforts. I have seen today how those could be in short order (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/6309).

Comment: @jww - sorry about that...I saw enough conversation on SO regarding this topic in my searches, that i assumed it was ok...felt in a grey area.

Comment: @riptusk331 it is *not* a grey area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Alpine base images are based on a compact tool set called [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/) and when you run `crond` here you're getting the BusyBox cron and not any other implementation.  Its [documentation](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) is a little sparse, but if you look at [the crond source](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/miscutils/crond.c) (in C) what you'll find is that there is not any redirection at all when it goes to run a job (see the non-sendmail version of `start_one_job`); the job's stdout and stderr are crond's stdout and stderr.  In Docker, since crond is the container primary process, that in turn becomes the container's output stream.

Anything that shows up in `docker logs` definitionally went to stdout or stderr or the container's main process.  If this cron implementation wrote your job's output directly there, there's nothing wrong or insecure with taking advantage of that.

In heavier-weight container orchestration systems, there is some way to run a container on a schedule (Kubernetes CronJobs, Nomad periodic jobs).  You might find it easier and more consistent with these systems to set up a container that runs your job once and then exits, and then to set up the *host's* cron to run your container (necessarily, as root).

Comment: Wow, thanks - did not realize it was a BusyBox implementation of cron. That's extremely helpful to know. If I DID want to maintain a log file of just cron, is there a best practice way to do so? As I've seen in some other answers, using `tail` results in that being the container's main process and not `cron`

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the CAP_SETGID to run `crond` as user, this can be a security risk if it is set to all busybox binary but you can use `dcron` package instead of busybox's builtin `crond` and set the `CAP_SETGID` just on that program. Here is what you need to add for Alpine, using `riptusk331` as running user

```
USER root
# crond needs root, so install dcron and cap package and set the capabilities 
# on dcron binary https://github.com/inter169/systs/blob/master/alpine/crond/README.md
RUN apk add --no-cache dcron libcap && \
    chown riptusk331:riptusk331 /usr/sbin/crond && \
    setcap cap_setgid=ep /usr/sbin/crond

USER riptusk331
```