# Can't self-sign certificate using self-generated openssh private key

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

OS: Linux
openssl version: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

I use

```sh
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

to generate my key `my-key` and `my-key.pub`.

I want to self-sign my certificate by

```sh
openssl req -new -subj "/C=GC/CN=foo" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:x.y.z" -addext "certificatePolicies = 1.2.3.4" -key ~/.ssh/my-key -out req.pem
```

and it turns out error:

```
error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

The start of my private key `my-key` is

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and I tried

```sh
openssl rsa -in my-key -outform pem > my-key.pem
```

to convert my private key to PEM format, and it turns out the same error.

I tried

```sh
ssh-keygen -p -N "" -m pem -f my-key
```

it says that this command changes file in place, but my file does not change at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Openssh Private Key to RSA Private Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994641/openssh-private-key-to-rsa-private-key)

Comment: @arved Unfortunately, this answer doesn't work for me, I will edit my question to add this situation.