# How to Generate ECDSA Key Pair for SSH in Go?

Tags: go, ssh, cryptography, rsa, ecdsa

I'm trying to generate ECDSA Key Pair for SSH with Go, but I find that the private key format is different from `ssh-keygen` and can't be accepted by GitHub.

Here's the 256-bit key pair generated via `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 256`:

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBOJWUhO+waiB+aKvXO0xC5XTL6P/X/TIzQ4hgdXkDfmAfntOj/HXRIu4GulCvJgUoyTiF5Qt9j9gK6Z17szUv3s= root@9e5eef4b58c5

-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAaAAAABNlY2RzYS
1zaGEyLW5pc3RwMjU2AAAACG5pc3RwMjU2AAAAQQTiVlITvsGogfmir1ztMQuV0y+j/1/0
yM0OIYHV5A35gH57To/x10SLuBrpQryYFKMk4heULfY/YCumde7M1L97AAAAsDs42wc7ON
sHAAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBOJWUhO+waiB+aKv
XO0xC5XTL6P/X/TIzQ4hgdXkDfmAfntOj/HXRIu4GulCvJgUoyTiF5Qt9j9gK6Z17szUv3
sAAAAgOpAIXW6rZQqgYZboSJXojH2diS26wfm6P3hn8cQVZrwAAAARcm9vdEA5ZTVlZWY0
YjU4YzUBAgMEBQYH
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Here's the generator code in Go:

```golang
// GenerateECDSAKeys generates ECDSA public and private key pair with given size for SSH.
func GenerateECDSAKeys(bitSize int) (pubKey string, privKey string, err error) {
    // generate private key
    var privateKey *ecdsa.PrivateKey
    if privateKey, err = ecdsa.GenerateKey(curveFromLength(bitSize), rand.Reader); err != nil {
        return
    }

    // encode public key
    var (
        bytes     []byte
        publicKey ssh.PublicKey
    )
    if publicKey, err = ssh.NewPublicKey(privateKey.Public()); err != nil {
        return
    }
    pubBytes := ssh.MarshalAuthorizedKey(publicKey)

    // encode private key
    if bytes, err = x509.MarshalECPrivateKey(privateKey); err != nil {
        return
    }
    privBytes := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{
        Type:  "ECDSA PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: bytes,
    })

    return string(pubBytes), string(privBytes), nil
}

func curveFromLength(l int) elliptic.Curve {
    switch l {
    case 224:
        return elliptic.P224()
    case 256:
        return elliptic.P256()
    case 348:
        return elliptic.P384()
    case 521:
        return elliptic.P521()
    }
    return elliptic.P384()
}
```

And generated result:

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBNYTtNRlEKh/harLSfIsSziDkEQ8E7OJ7azhTBJi1Qx+fDa6dGg9f/vudGEizJ5d9TINVLTP+Jemwg6FBhajiVA=

-----BEGIN ECDSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIEGZZ/4aD6tf0sc1ovyctlGWRSFp7RGw5ovRONZKLg4eoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAE1hO01GUQqH+FqstJ8ixLOIOQRDwTs4ntrOFMEmLVDH58Nrp0aD1/
++50YSLMnl31Mg1UtM/4l6bCDoUGFqOJUA==
-----END ECDSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So why SSH private key was so different after the generation, and how to make it works?

Comment: OpenSSH uses both the SEC1 format and the OpenSSH format for private EC keys, see [here](https://coolaj86.com/articles/the-openssh-private-key-format/) for details. The Go code generates a private EC key in SEC1 format. However, the header and footer are wrong, they actually contain EC instead of ECDSA, i.e. replace `Type: "ECDSA PRIVATE KEY"` with `Type: "EC PRIVATE KEY"`. Maybe the SEC1 key will be accepted then. If not, you probably need a Go library that supports the newer OpenSSH format. Note that you can convert between the formats with e.g. ssh-keygen.

Comment: BTW you misspelled 384, and SSH doesn't allow P-224 so there's no point in generating it. Otherwise concur with @Topaco. Nearly crossdupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/200935/how-do-i-determine-if-an-existing-ssh-private-key-is-secure and as linked there https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39279/stronger-encryption-for-ssh-keys

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for pointing out and the reference! However I used P-256 actually.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks! I didn't realize that the header matters. After the replacement, the Go generated SSH keys work for both GitHub Push/Pull and SSH Login. Do you mind writing a detailed answer and explain about the headers, so I can accept it as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: @CeciliaWong - You' re welcome, I' ve posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSH uses different formats for private EC keys, the SEC1 (as generated by your Go code), the PKCS#8 or the newer OpenSSH format (as generated with the *ssh-keygen* command). This is described [here](https://coolaj86.com/articles/the-openssh-private-key-format/), which also contains a more detailed explanation of the OpenSSH format. The SEC1 format is explained e.g. in this [post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48707).

The current Go code generates a SEC1 key with *wrong* header and footer. This turned out to be the cause of the problem! To fix the bug, `ECDSA` must be replaced by `EC` in header and footer:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

i.e. in the Go code in the `EncodeToMemory()` call `Type: "ECDSA PRIVATE KEY"` must be replaced by `Type: "EC PRIVATE KEY"`.

Note that a conversion between the formats is also possible e.g. with *ssh-keygen*. For instance

```
ssh-keygen -p -N "" -f data.key
```

converts the SEC1 key contained in `data.key` to the OpenSSH format, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817907/9014097).