# Pgadmin 4 returns "No password or public key available!"

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm following the steps for [How to connect PGAdmin4 to DB through SSH tunnel with Public key authentication](https://medium.com/3-elm-erlang-elixir/faq-how-to-connect-pgadmin4-to-db-through-ssh-tunnel-with-public-key-authentication-b351750c20be).

I point it to the identity file I generated through OpenSSH (has no extension) but whenever I hit save it says "No password or public key available!"

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the answer: Need to convert the SSH private key to a RSA private key using

```
ssh-keygen -p -N "" -m pem -f /path/to/key
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994641/openssh-private-key-to-rsa-private-key)

Comment: I used puttyGen to do this as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/72264414/244811 but, this worked for me.  Interesting that my key was named "id_rsa" but was actually in SSH -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY----- format.