# Sign jwt with RSA OpenSSH keys, in python with pyJWT

Tags: ssh, jwt, rsa, ssh-keygen

I have generated an ssh key with:

```bash
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

Resulting in this:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Now trying to generate a `jwt` with this key:

```py
import jwt

key = open("~/.ssh/id_rsa", "r").read()
token = jwt.encode(
    claim={'iss': 'me'},
    key=key,
    algorithm='RS256'
)
```

I got the error:

```
ValueError: ('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [_OpenSSLErrorWithText(code=503841036, lib=60, reason=524556, reason_text=b'error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported')])
```

Is it not possible to use openSSH key to sign the data?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994641/openssh-private-key-to-rsa-private-key) help?

Answer (score 1):

PyJWT requires the Cryprography library for RSA, see [here](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installation-cryptography). Cryptography in turn supports the OpenSSH format, see [here](https://cryptography.io/en/3.1/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/?highlight=openssh%20import%20rsa#openssh-private-key) and [here](https://cryptography.io/en/3.1/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/?highlight=openssh%20import%20rsa#openssh-public-key), e.g.:

```py
import jwt
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

private_key_OpenSSH = b'''-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3Blbn....suThWLDRnmD
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----'''

private_key = serialization.load_ssh_private_key(private_key_OpenSSH, password=None) 
encoded = jwt.encode({"some": "payload"}, private_key, algorithm="RS256")
...
```

If the key is secured with a password, additionally the [bcrypt](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/) module must be installed.

Comment: I should have started by reading the ```jwt``` documentation , it's all there.