# Trying to connect to remote server using python sshtunnel module. Keep getting password required Error

Tags: python, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect to a remote server using the sshtunnel module in python. but it keeps giving me the following error

ERROR   | Password is required for key C:\Users\folder/.ssh\id_rsa

```py
key_file = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\folder\\.ssh', 'id_rsa')

server = sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('remote_ip_address',22),
    ssh_username="user",
    ssh_pkey= key_file,
    ssh_private_key_password="password",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306),
    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
)
```

Used to work just fine. Dont understand what has changed and why this is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check `id_rsa` file?

in previous stackoverflow answers

([sshtunnel doesn't recognize private key password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167788/sshtunnel-doesnt-recognize-private-key-password))

said `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` is need top of the rsa file
(also need `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` end of the rsa file).

i have same problem, when i use bastion server aws ec2.

but in my case, i was wrong pkey. `.pem` type key is needed